# Rails 4 ActiveRecord::Store permit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help me with the store attributes in Rails 4. I have the following lines in my `user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  store :settings, accessors: [:provider, :api, :background]
  ....
end
```

I am trying to permit these params in `users_controller.rb`

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :token, settings: [:provider, :api, :background])
end
```

However, the `:settings` serialized array is empty.

Comment: Can you share the server logs generated while creating/updating a user.

Answer (score 0):

Change `user_params` as below:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :token, :provider, :api, :background)
end
```

`settings` is not required while `permitting params` as you have direct accessors defined for the `stored settings`.

I am assuming that you have already created a field named `settings` in the `users` table.
If you haven't then create a migration for adding the column as:

`rails g migration AddSettingsToUser settings:string`

After this run `rake db:migrate`

This will create `settings` column in `users` table.

Comment: i want to know why you are passing settings as parameter if you are creating separate column for settings ..?

Comment: @Mayank I am NOT passing settings as parameter. Take a look at my user_params method. In fact, I removed it which OP was originally passing.

Answer (score 0):

This one will solve your problem:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :token, :settings)
end
```

As `:setting` is defined as a text column in your controller's table, it is sufficient to mention it in the `user_params`